# Why does my data visual in ggplot2 display 4 significant figures when I specify 3?

Tags: r, ggplot2, significant-digits

I'm trying to create a bar chart the displays the unemployment rate for people who majored in the social sciences for 4 different age groups. In my visual, I want to display the unemployment rate on each bar, but I'm having trouble getting the labels on my bars to display 3 significant figures.

Here is my code:

```
social_vs <- social_ur %>%
  ggplot(aes(
    x = age_group,
    y = unemployment_rate_avg,
    fill = age_group
  )) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(signif(unemployment_rate_avg, digits = 3)), vjust = 2.0))

social_vs1 <- social_vs +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Unemployment Rate", labels = scales::percent, n.breaks = 4) +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "Age Group", labels = c(
    "25 to 34",
    "35 to 44",
    "45 to 54",
    "55 to 64")) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set2") +
  theme_grey() +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  labs(title = "Social: unemployment rate by age group")

social_vs1
```

As you can see, I specify

```
signif(unemployment_rate_avg, digits = 3)
```

yet my visual still displays 4 significant figures.

I've included a png of the visual created by running the above code.

[Social Science Unemployment Rates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVpRX.png)

Comment: You are probably looking for `scales::percent(x, accuracy = 0.01)`.

Comment: The issue is that `scales::percent` by default uses "uses a heuristic that should ensure breaks have the minimum number of digits needed to show the difference between adjacent values". Therefore I would suggest to set the àccuracy` via scales::percent

Comment: Thank you so much @teunbrand. That adjustment worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (not tested as no data was shared):

```
library(ggplot2)
#Code
social_vs <- social_ur %>%
  ggplot(aes(
    x = age_group,
    y = unemployment_rate_avg,
    fill = age_group
  )) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 3))), vjust = 2.0))

social_vs1 <- social_vs +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Unemployment Rate", labels = scales::percent, n.breaks = 4) +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "Age Group", labels = c(
    "25 to 34",
    "35 to 44",
    "45 to 54",
    "55 to 64")) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set2") +
  theme_grey() +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  labs(title = "Social: unemployment rate by age group")
```